# Init process interaction with shell cripts

Tags: linux, shell, init

Nearly all linux courses say that init process, given the run level, will execute appropriate shell scripts to initialize the enivronment. But non of the courses describe in detail how init process does it.

As I understand the init process is basically a C program, much like any Hello World C code. Only much more sophisticated. Does anyone knows how this C program actually runs through all the scripts and invokes them?

I would really appreciate any answer and especially if you have a link to an example source code.

Comment: source code of sysvinit: (http://linux.softpedia.com/progDownload/SysVinit-Download-6314.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find explanations of what it does in different documentation:

- http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Installation_Guide/s2-boot-init-shutdown-init.html
- http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=4

and you can find its source code over there:

- [init.h](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/sysvinit/trunk/src/init.h?revision=27&root=sysvinit&view=markup)
- [init.c](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/sysvinit/trunk/src/init.c?revision=116&root=sysvinit&view=markup)

basically, `init` as process 1, has for role to `fork()` every application on your system. If you boot linux with the command line `init=/bin/sh` at boot time, process `1` forked by the kernel will be a shell. The sysvinit program makes it a bit more easy to handle a complex boot. It adds the concept of runlevels, define basic environment etc.. so that makes it easy to boot a system and have many services, and not only a shell. All that part is well explained in the documentations I gave you.

> Does anyone knows how this C program actually runs through all the scripts and invokes them?

Well, is as simple as in your question. When you boot your system, init reads the `inittab` file, figures out what are your preferences (what is the default runlevel? what program to spawn? how many consoles?..), and for the chosen runlevel will fork a shell that will execute the startup script. Then that shell script will makes its way up to the shell script you activated from `/etc/init.d`. Usually the shell script part is very distribution-specific, that's why I gave you two links about that, and you may find it is different on ubuntu and debian...

For more details on the source code, you may want to start at the bottom of `init.c` which contains init's mainloop.

And +1 on your question for your curiosity!

Comment: Thanks man, you really helped me. Can I ask another question? For example, init process finds out that for example current run level is 2, then because it has access to file system, it will find out the content of /etc/rc2.d directory and FOR EACH script in that folder it will fork a shell program. Pls correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: not exactly, it executes the program configured in inittab for the given runlevel, within the `l0:0:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 0` lines (that one being what debian linux uses, it may be different for other distributions). So that's `/etc/init.d/rc`'s role to find the `/etc/rc*.d/*` file and fork them.